# Using OpenCV GPU module in JAVA

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv, javacpp

I am using the wrapped version of the `OpenCV` image processing library for java (`opencv java api` by [OpenCv](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html)) in order to detect cars' plates at the real time. Where in order to do so, I must gain the maximum possible processing speed for better performance, so I intended to try moving the calculations into the **GPU** where the `OpenCV` library has added, since 2010, what is called the [OpenCV GPU module](http://opencv.org/platforms/cuda.html) into the `c++ library`, supported by `NVIDIA-CUDA`. However, After a lot of research, I find that this **GPU module** is not supported in any of the `opencv java api` versions.

**Then the question says:**

Is it ever possible in **JAVA**  to move the `OpenCv` processing procedures to the GPU without this GPU module? or is there any wrapped version out there for the `OpenCv` that supports this module in **JAVA**? or any other ideas?!!

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The OpenCV does not yet provide the GPU type of Mat object, but you can take a look at JavaCV which is a complete wrap of OpenCV.

Comment: Can I ask for an update regarding this? Same situation here...only in 2019

Answer (score -1):

Speed and Java are two opposite sides but if at all you want to accelerate ops by CUDA version of OpenCV, i would say write [JNI wrapper interface](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) to access them inside your Java Code.

Comment: Thanks @Milind, sorry but I don't agree with u at this point, java could be one of the fastest high-level languages especially if you know how to use it at maximum performance... Besides, i know that i can wrap my own version but that would be my ever last choice.

Comment: @HMaster Can it be faster than C/C++? Moreover, there is no other way to call CUDA APIs other than making JNI calls.

Comment: Thanks again @Milind, of course, it couldn't be faster than C/C++ however it is much more productive, Concerning the JNI calls I agree that it is the only way to communicate with CUDA or any other C/C++ library, but I am looking for an already wrapped version of OpenCV that supports GPUs instead of coding it myself (that I will do when I find no other easy choices). Anyway I highly appreciate your reply, **thanks**.